# Add elements dynamically to the nested list using Knockout.js Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm using Knockout-3.2.0.js in mvc4 application. I have a list of FieldInfo class, which contains a list of itself.
FieldInfo contains field_id, field_name, file_name and list. After doing some manipulation, my action returns a list to the view. I setup everything in my view:

```
 @{
      var initialData = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
 }
 LineItemFields = ko.observableArray(@initialData);
```

Observable array is initially a list which has a list itself.
Everything works fine until the user clicks the Add button. My add button in viewModel has the following:

```
 addLineItem = function () {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.toJS(LineItemFields), function (item) {
                    item.LineItemValues.push({ "FieldValue": "0", "FieldID": 1})
                })
            }
```

LineItemFields is the main list which has 7 child (as an example) and those 7 child have a list each, requirement is to add a new element to the lists of those 7 children each.
I tried debugging and everything went well but it still doesn't add the new row. 
Following is in template binding:

```
<script id="LineItemDataTemplate" type="text/html">
        <td data-bind="foreach: $data['LineItemValues']"><input type="text" data-bind="value: FieldValue, enable: $parent.isUpdatable" class="table-column" /></td>
</script>

<table>
    <tr data-bind="template: {name: 'LineItemDataTemplate', foreach: LineItemFields}"> </tr>
</table>
```

Q1: Does the inner lists have to be observable as their parent is?

Q2: If not, What is wrong with the addLineItem function?

Comment: can you include what your model look like.

Comment: Hey @Nathan, following is my model class:

        public int configseqid { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public int FieldID { get; set; }
        public bool IsLineItemTableSpecificField { get; set; }
        public bool isVisible { get; set; }
        public bool isUpdatable { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
        public List<FieldInfo> LineItemValues { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no answer up to date and i got it working so i thought to post an answer to benefit others. I made the following changes to my viewModel.

```
 //added the observableArray to each item in the parent list
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(LineItemFields(), function (item) {
                item.LineItemValues = ko.observableArray(item.LineItemValues);
            })

 //Removed ko.toJS(..) from LineItemFields and applied ()
 addLineItem = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(LineItemFields(), function (item) {
        item.LineItemValues.push({ "FieldValue": "0", "FieldID": 1});
    })
 }
```

Comment: yep, that's right.  If you expect something to change, and you want the rest of the application to react to those changes, you should wrap it inside an observable.